# Pandas dataframe: alignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, alignment

I'm trying to give my custom style to my dataframe visualization.
Here is my example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan
df.style.bar(subset=['A', 'B'], color='#d65f5f').hide_index().set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

my problem is that column names are aligned to the right.
I couldn't find a way to correct it. help me with this, please!

Comment: are you saying that 1.0 through 10.0 should be the columns? Or that you want ABCDE to be left aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these when printing:

```
 print(df.to_string(justify='center', index=False))  
 print(df.to_string(justify='left', index=False))
```